Hard Disk Showing but no format option
Hard Disk Showing but no format option. I have installed ubuntu yesterday with AHCI sata configuration. During installation, I was able to see it and now it's on available for format.


Was it formatted before? Or new blank drive?  Is it gpt partitioned? You have to do that first. Then add partitions. But if it was MBR(msdos) and you change to gpt, it totally erases drive. Or was drive NTFS and Windows hibernation is on?

Edit your question and add the above information.
